# Wordpress - separate blog page not showing the posts but showing the homepage of the custom theme

Tags: wordpress, posts

Wordpress - separate blog page not showing the posts and showing the homepage of the custom theme... (not redirecting to home page just showing in place of blog page with the link  *http://www.example.com/blog* on the addressbar of the browser)

As I have already adjust the setting on **wp-admin** following as
**SETTING>Reading>
A static page
Front page to Home (homepage of the theme)** and
**posts to blog (separate blog page of the theme)**

And Blog page consist the following code

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) :
  // Start the Loop.
  while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
  endwhile;
  // Previous/next post navigation.
  next_previous_paging_nav();
else :
  // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
  get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;

get_footer(); ?>
```

And the Home page of the theme is almost static page.

Comment: I'm not sure what theme you are using but have you selected the blog template inside your blog page?

Comment: Yes! I have also selected the blog template for blog page on the wp-admin Pages>Blog>Page Attribute>Template>Blog

Comment: I am using custom theme

Comment: Any assistance for my problem will highly appreciate.

Comment: are you getting a no posts found or are you getting something completely different on the page?

Comment: The separate blog page when click on the menu link goes to completely homepage and not showing 'no post found' message.

Comment: are you able to go to the direct link without clicking on the menu items through permalink?  example.com/blog

Comment: when click on the main menu link say 'BLOG' it goes to example.com/blog (through permalink) but displays the home page instead of blog template page.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your static home page template is not in a file called `index.php` or `home.php`. If WordPress detects any one of those files it will automatically assume it is the template for your posts. Therefore create a `front-page.php` or similar for your static home page and `index.php` or `home.php` for your posts page.